# How to Include RoundUp in a Script Formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script that is inserting formulas via script to run calculations as data is entered in the spreadsheet. The last line obviously doesn't work but I am wondering if there is anyway to include the typical RoundUp function in a formula like the Net Height Calculation one. Thanks for any advice.

```
function MH484020() {

    //Grab the active spreadsheet

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    //Find the first last row with data in it

    var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();

    //Use the last row with data in it to place forumulas below it

    var range = sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,2);
    range.setValue('DRAINAGE STR. 48-4020')

     var range = sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3)
     range.setValue('484020')

    //Set data validation for steps or not

    var range = sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,4);
    var rule =    SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Yes','No'])
      .build();
    range.setDataValidation(rule);

    //Covers Calculation

    sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,7).setFormula("=F" + (lastrow+1));

      //Net Height Calculation

    sheet.getRange("H" + (lastrow+1)).setFormula("=E" + (lastrow+1) + "-(F" +  (lastrow+1) + "*1.5)");

    //Mastic Calculation

     sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,9).setFormula("=Roundup"( + "H" + (lastrow+1)));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some quotes in the wrong place

```
sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,9).setFormula("=Roundup(H" + (lastrow+1) + ")");
```

if you have problems with this kind of thing first put the formula in a cell as you normally would and make sure it calculates correctly.then copy the formula and paste it between paranthesis setFormula( )

```
.setFormula(=E5-(F5*1.5));
```

next put quotes at the beginning and the end of the formula

```
.setFormula("=E5-(F5*1.5)");
```

next replace each row number with: (including the quotes)

```
" + (lastrow+1) + "
```

as in:

```
.setFormula("=E" + (lastrow+1) + "-(F" +  (lastrow+1) + "*1.5)");
```

if a row number ends the formula then you should leave out the ending plus sign and quote.

```
=E5-F5
.setFormula("=E" + (lastrow+1) + "-F" +  (lastrow+1));
```